# TSP with multiple visits

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, tsp

Can you please suggest possible approaches for the following problem:

Find a path through graph vertices so that the distance (sum of edges weights) between two vertex $i$ occurrences would be no more than $D_i$. It is obviously infinite, so I want to have a generator for this path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We have studied an online version of the problem (in a geometric setting): http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/josuomel/publications/algosensors-2008-backlog-paper.html

Comment: @Jukka, the page is not accessible.

Comment: Here is a new link that should work: https://users.ics.aalto.fi/suomela/minimum-backlog/

Answer (score 2):

This problem is PSPACE-complete even in the case in which the edge weights obey the triangle inequality. See

- Hsi-Ming Ho, Joel Ouaknine, *[The Cyclic-Routing UAV Problem is PSPACE-Complete](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2874)*, FoSSaCS 2015